# Who has the biggest breasts in the Naruto series?

Tags: naruto

Right now, I think it is Tsunade, but is there anyone else who has bigger breasts than Tsunade?

It seems in Leaf village, Hinata is 2nd. From *Road to Naruto*, Chapter 1, page 11:

[image]

Comment: There's [Samui](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Samui) of Team Samui... [Tsunade's measurements were given by Jiraiya](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/how-did-jiraiya-find-out-tsunades-breast-size). Measurements of other characters were not revealed. Hence the comparison would be visual guesses

Comment: Go answer it, Ero Sennin!

Comment: This question is incredibly stupid, but I don't think it's primarily opinion-based.

Comment: This isn't opinion based. He's looking for facts people. He wants to know who actually has the largest chest.

Comment: @LukifurHelbringer It is primarly opinion-based, because there are isn't any site that actually has measurements. This means it's only visual, which is not a real comparison.

Comment: @pap - just because there's no info on it doesn't make it opinion based - a valid answer (like ero's) is that there is no information

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Think about what you just said. Without info, there are no evidence and without evidence there is no answer. What I am trying to say is, that there isn't any measurements for this, so it's only what you see. And as far as I know in anime you cannot say something for sure , until the editor makes a databook of some sort.  So without a databook, it is opinion based. We all know that this site needs answers with enough evidence, and in this case we don't have enough evidence to say if this is the right answer or wrong.

Comment: @pap I understand what you're trying to say - yes answers could potentially be opinion-based - but there is definitely a definitive answer, whether or not it has been revealed.

If you still disagree with the reopening - perhaps post on meta, or come talk on chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe- as we're starting to take up a lot of room in the comments.

Comment: LOL!! Are we including the filler episodes as well? I might just rewatch everything for the sake of this question...

Comment: Is your name Jiraya? Or PERVY sage, as Naruto called him. This question is totally pervy.

Comment: only oppai lovers would be concerned about this lol

Answer (score 22):

Only Tsunade's measurements were revealed in the series ([courtesy of Jiraiya](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/how-did-jiraiya-find-out-tsunades-breast-size)). And I don't think the databooks include details like bust measurements. So the comparisons would be based on the appearance solely. Visual comparison isn't a good way of getting the right answer.

But if you're looking for another character who has noticeably big oppai, there's [Samui](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Samui) of Kumogakure:

[image]

Comment: surprisingly appropriate username...